# npm install is failing on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

On looking into it it looks like some version issues:

[image: Screeshot of error]

My Mac OS X version is 10.11.1

Comment: Instead of trying to build things like this from scratch you can save yourself a lot of grief by using one of the better package managers for OS X, e.g. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) - just install Homebrew and then `sudo brew install npm`.

Comment: Did you confirm you've met all the prerequisites for using node-gyp on OSX?